# Are C Shared Object Backwards Compatible (Standard-Wise)

Tags: c, shared-libraries, backwards-compatibility, c11

I have a rather simple question:

I want to write a library (to be used in other projects via a `.so` file) which uses the C11-Specific `_Generic` keyword. I would love it if projects using the library did not need to compile their project using the C11 standard. Is this possible?

PS: I Googled a bit and didn't see an answer, and I'm on my phone, so, as a forewarning, there's no "Possible Duplicates" list on my screen.

Comment: I don't think the binary generated would have anything to do with the C11 specifics used in the code, why don't you just run a simple test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .so file will know nothing about `_Generic`, the decisions that this feature makes are at compile time.

What you should worry about are your header files. If you'd have "stray" `_Generic` in there and a client has a pre-C11 compiler, this would crash. So you'd have to `#if/#else` the part of your headers with `__STDC_VERSION__` to protect pre-C11 compilers to see this.